# Nested multiprocessing: How to terminate properly?

Tags: python, nested, multiprocessing

I have a python script that implement two levels of multiprocessing:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Lock

if __name__ == '__main__':

    pl1s = []
    for ip1 in range(10):
        pl1 = Process(target=process_level1, args=(...))
        pl1.start()
        pl1s.append(pl1)

    # do somehting for awhile, e.g. for 24 hours

    # time to terminate
    # ISSUE: this terminates process_level1 processes
    #    but not process_level2 ones
    for pl1 in pl1s:
        pl1.terminate()


def process_level1(...):

    # subscriibe to external queue
    #
    with queue.open(name_of_external_queue, 'r') as subq:
        qInternal = Queue()

        pl2s = []
        for ip2 in range(3):
            pl2 = Process(target=process_level2, args=(qInternal))
            pl2.start()
            pl2s.append(pl2)

        # grab messages from external queue and push them to 
        # process_level2 processes to process
        #
        while True:
                    message = subq.read()
            qInternal.put(m)

def process_level2(qInternal):

    while True:
        message = qInternal.get()
        # do something with date form message
```

So in main I launch a bunch of slave subprocesses `process_level1` each of which launches a bunch of its own subprocesses `process_level2`. `Main` is supposed to run for a predefined amount of time (e.g. 24 hrs) then terminate everything. The problem is that the code above terminates the 1st layer of subprocesses but not the 2nd one.

How should I do this to terminate both layers at the same time?

(Maybe an important) caveat: I guess one approach would be to set up an internal queue to communicate from `main` to `process_level1` and then send a signal to each `process_level1` subprocess to terminate their respective subprocesses. The problem is that `process_level1` runs an infinite loop reading messages form an external queue. So I am not sure where and how I would check for the terminate signal from main.

Comment: If this is linux (and you control the level1 source), you can use os.setpgid() to add all of the processes to a single process group and signal them in mass.

Comment: @tdelaney Is there any sort of interrupt message that I can send to a group of processes which can be handled inside those processes with something similar to a KeyboardInterrupt exception handling? Thx

Comment: Supposing you are in the parent program and have used its pid as the process group id. You can the send a keyboard interrupt to all of them via `os.kill(-os.getpid(), signal.SIGINT)`.

Comment: I see, thanks. After I call `p = Process(...)` to create a process, do I `os.setpgid(p.pid, root_pid)` before or after `p.start()`, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: Do os.getpid() at any time. Do os.setpgid() after p.start () - p.pid won't exist until its started.